# How to set bot status without WATCHING/STREAMING/etc?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js, bots

I tried to set a custom status for my Bot in discord.js and it worked. But now I want to set this status without a type of word like WATCHING/STREAMING and so on.

Is that possible?

Comment: I use `"Watching you type..."` in my bot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am sorry but no, that's not possible in discord.js.